# Scalability of Hyperledger fabric to support bulk data processing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to update my data to Blockchain platform using fabric through Rest API. I will pass **200** parameters per sec for every day via API call. My total load will be **20 GB** per day.

Is it feasible to implement with Fabric? How can I store and retrieve data efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Every transaction in Fabric, is 3KB of additional data.
Your best bet is to aggregate data or store it off-chain